# React Native Redux actions returns first before storing the dispatch

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, fetch

Don't know if I followed a wrong tutorial.
But when I try to launch a fetch action it is always return null array on the first few seconds.(based on my initial state) probably because Endpoint provided a response a little delayed.
or I'm not calling the stored valued correctly

Here the logs, you can see upon firing a OnPressIN two times and calling a function

```
 LOG  Running "uCon" with {"rootTag":1}
 LOG  [] <--- First onPress
 LOG  [] <--- Second onPress
 LOG  [{"member_id": 14987, "number": "(03) xxxx x495", "status_id": 3}, {"member_id": 14988, "number": "(03) xxxx x123", "status_id": 3}, {"member_id": 14990, "number": "(03) xxxx x125", "status_id": 3}] <--- Third onPress
```

Here's the action

```
export const setEmail = email => dispatch => {

    dispatch({
        type: SET_EMAIL,
        payload: email,
    });

};

export const getMemberEmail = (emailParam) => {

//It probably return first before waiting for the dispatch below to finish?
    return (dispatch) => {
        fetch(API_URL + "/query-email", {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                email: emailParam
            })
        })
            .then((res) => {
                // If response was successful parse the json and dispatch an update
                if (res.ok) {
                    res.json().then((emailCheck) => {
                        dispatch({
                            type: GET_MEMBER_EMAIL,
                            payload: emailCheck
                        });
                    });
                } else {
                    // response wasn't successful so dispatch an error
                    console.log("Unable to fetch")
                }
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                // Runs if there is a general JavaScript error.
                console.log(err);
            });
    };
};
```

Here's the reducer

```
import { SET_EMAIL, GET_MEMBER_EMAIL, SET_LOGIN_WARNING_1, SET_LOGIN_WARNING_2, SET_EMAIL_MODAL, SET_SERVICES_MODAL } from "../actions";

const initialState = {
    memberEmailCheck: [],
    email: '',
    loginWarning1: false,
    loginWarning2: false,
    emailModal: true,
    servicesModal: false,
}

function loginReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case GET_MEMBER_EMAIL:
            return { ...state, memberEmailCheck: action.payload };
        case SET_EMAIL:
            return { ...state, email: action.payload };
        case SET_LOGIN_WARNING_1:
            return { ...state, loginWarning1: action.payload }
        case SET_LOGIN_WARNING_2:
            return { ...state, loginWarning2: action.payload }
        case SET_EMAIL_MODAL:
            return { ...state, emailModal: action.payload }
        case SET_SERVICES_MODAL:
            return { ...state, servicesModal: action.payload }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}


export default loginReducer
```

and lastly here'sthe store

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import modalReducer from "./reducers/modalReducers";
import loginReducer from "./reducers/loginReducers";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({ modalReducer, loginReducer });

export const Store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));
```

Now the component

```
import { getMemberEmail, setEmail, setLoginWarning1, setLoginWarning2, setEmailModal, setServicesModal } from '../redux/actions';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';


export default function LogIn({ navigation, route }) {

  const backgroundImage = "../../assets/images/background.png";
  const logoHeader = "../../assets/images/uConnectedHeader.png";
  const { memberEmailCheck, email, loginWarning1, loginWarning2, emailModal, servicesModal } = useSelector(state => state.loginReducer);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  // const [welcomeModal, setWelcomeModal] = useState(true);

  const checkEMail = async () => {
      await dispatch(getMemberEmail(email));
      console.log(memberEmailCheck); <-- Here's the console that I used to track the result
      // if (memberEmailCheck.message === 'The email address provided was not found to match a service') {
      //   dispatch(setLoginWarning1(true));
      // } else {
      //   // dispatch(setEmailModal(false));
      //   // dispatch(setServicesModal(true));
      //   validateMemberEmail();
      //   console.log(memberEmailCheck);
      // }  
  };
```

and this function is called via an onPressIn

```
<TextInput
                style={styles.modalInput}
                placeholder="Email"
                onChangeText={(value) => dispatch(setEmail(value))} />

<Pressable
                style={({ pressed }) => [
                  {
                    backgroundColor: "#FD6B89",
                    borderRadius: 10,
                    margin: 10,
                    opacity: pressed
                      ? 0.5
                      : 1,
                  }]}
                onPressIn={() => { checkEMail() }}
              >
```

I highly suspect that I'm calling the state when it is not being stored properly.
But I exhausted on trying to find a way make the action to wait for dispatch GET_MEMBER_EMAIL to finish before returning to the component.

I tried async await, promise or I'm really knowledgeable on this one.

Hope you can help me.

Thank you!

Comment: You will not get the memberEmailCheck right after your API call write that console.log(memberEmailCheck) just outside of your function email check.  react will rerender every time when an edit happens in your reducer.  so the console will print [] initially and it log proper value when API will get success

Comment: ohhh is that so, then I'm missing the useEffect hook, Thank you very much for the advised! big help @sojin